# USB camera originally designed for PC hardware and kernel 2.x

Tags: raspbian, usb, camera, kernel

I wonder if this is off-topic. Basically, I want to get some idea before spending expensive money on international mail order.

The question is really getting comment on how compatible is Linux on webcam hardware?

I am evaluating buying an USB camera which specification is compatible with Linux Kernal 2.xx and PC hardware.

I want to use with RPi Model B (vs original specification of PC hardware) and Raspbian Wheezy with kernel 3.10 (vs original spec. on PC Linux and 2.x Kernel )?

Do I need to re-compile the kernel for the camera 'driver portion' (from 2.x to 3.x kernel)? Is that under area of V4L, Video for Linux?

Comment: Have you checked http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Webcams ?

Comment: Yes, I checked the webcam list. The intended camera purchase is industrial camera for computer vision as photo  https://www.google.com/search?q=industrial+camera&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ai6fU_6QLYetkgXO-YDYBg&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg&biw=1462&bih=833

Comment: I think the question is unanswerable unless someone is already using the identical camera with the Pi.

Comment: Yes, it could be that way. Since it is expensive, I am hoping to get some comment/idea.

Comment: I meant if, over some time, no body comment/answer, the intended path may be too far away from 'typical' and we can scale back from RPi hardware to PC hardware, with either PC Linux or PC Windows.